# What permission to set to check any member in a Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

The FQL used is:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=<uid> and page_id=<page_id>;
```

however, this returns empty set, even the `uid` is a verified member of the page.
I think it should be the permission problem.

How to make it works?

Comment: The query works just fine with basic permissions. You might be doing some mistake while feeding the UID and/or PAGE_ID.

Comment: I am rather sure with the UID and Page ID.
Does the UID need to be a friend?

Comment: You can't query the users that liked a page, that's privacy violation and facebook won't allow it.

Comment: The criteria is that the user must have allowed your APP to access his/her information.